# cant add migration to ef 7

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am still in the process of porting my old MVC project to the latest asp.net 5 MVC and EntityFramework 7.  To accomplish this I first reverse engineered an existing database from the old project using the ef commands.  That created all of my model classes correctly (or mostly so).  I have manually edited the code to get through all of the initial errors.  I have that compiling with almost no additional code from the original project.  In other words I only have the model classes, and the DbContext class so far in the solution.  All of this is in an assembly and I have no migrations at all in the codebase, just the Migrations directory.  What I thought would make sense is to add a migration to baseline the database from what was reverse engineered.  I should mention that my DbContext inherits from IdentityDbContext

```
public partial class STOrmContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
}
```

My project is split into two components. All database and models in an assembly, and MVC stuff in a separate project.

[image]

when I type

```
dnx ef command migrations add Initial
```

I get the following error message

```
The entity type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a key to be defined.
```

I guess I just don't really understand how to bootstrap a legacy database into EntintyFramework 7. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you override the `OnModelCreating` method of your `STOrmContext` ?

Comment: yes actually, and actually I found the answer myself.  It turns out it was a couple of things I was not addressing.  1. When I reverse engineered the old database it created models for the identity stuff from the legacy application.  I deleted those.  I also needed to call the base OnModelCreating() so that it could configure Identity stuff.  I guess I should have paid more attention to what was really happening before jumping to a question on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

It turns out it was a couple of things I was not addressing.

- When I reverse engineered the old database it created models for the
  identity stuff from the legacy application.
- I deleted those.
- I also needed to call the base OnModelCreating() so that it could configure
  Identity stuff.

  ```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }
  ```

I guess I should have paid more attention to what was really happening before jumping to a question on StackOverflow